# .NET Error Closing serial port BaseStream error is only available when the port is open

Tags: c#, .net, stream, serial-port

I'm using the .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort using the BaseStream as suggested in this post [If you *must* use .NET System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)

But when I try to close the port or the baseStream, an **System.InvalidOperationException** is raised saying "The BaseStream is only available when the port is open"

This is  my code:

```
    private void ActionStarted()
    {
        //ajusta el puerto
        setupSerial();

        serial.Open();  //conecta al plc
        byte[] buffer = new byte[15];
        Action kickoffRead = null;

        if (serial.IsOpen) 
        {
            kickoffRead = delegate()
            {
                serial.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length,
                    delegate(IAsyncResult ar)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int actualLength = serial.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
                            byte[] received = new byte[actualLength];
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, received, 0, actualLength);
                            raiseAppSerialDataEvent(received);
                        }
                        catch 
                        {
                           //do something
                        }

                        kickoffRead();

                    }, null);
            };
            kickoffRead();
        }

    }

//<-- here is where the error occurs -->
 private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
        serial.BaseStream.Flush();
        serial.BaseStream.Close();
        serial.Close();            
         }
```

I read somewhere that the serial port should be close on a different thread but I can't find that, so any thoughts??

Thanks!!

Comment: It's extremely likely that you are either not actually opening the port, or have closed it elsewhere. Without [a good code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's not possible to state anything more specific than that.

Comment: Hard to see the point of re-implementing the DataReceived event.  Basic bug is that you keep calling BeginRead(), even after you got the exception that told you that the port was closed.

Comment: ActionStarted() is only called on the onLoad event and port.close() is not called until the window is closed, so,   on, I'm calling beginRead any where else, that is not the case and that is why I'm posting my problem. Thanks

Comment: franko,I can't help you with your issue, but how/where did you implement  raiseAppSerialDataEvent(received)?

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problem as you described. Basically I solved with a proper disposal of the serial port resources and a check on port status before calling reading action. Here is the full code that open the port, read and close it.

```
    public bool Open()
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {

            this.serialPort.Open();
            result = true;
            startReading = StartAsyncSerialReading;
            startReading();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.Close();
            result = false;
        }
        return result;

    }

    private void StartAsyncSerialReading()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

        serialPort.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, bufferLength, delegate(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                if (serialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    actualReadLength = serialPort.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);                        
                    received = new byte[actualReadLength];

                    DoYourStuffWithDataBuffer();
                }
            }

            catch (IOException exc)
            {
                //handleAppSerialError(exc);
            }

            if (serialPort.IsOpen)
                startReading();

        }, null);

    }

    protected Stream GetStream()
    {
        return this.serialPort.BaseStream;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)                
                this.serialPort.Dispose();

            this.disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        this.serialPort.Close();
        this.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Given the use of SuppressFinzalize in the case Close() is called, that implies you're not going to try to re-Open() the socket?

Answer (score 0):

As Luca correctly pointed out, you should check the status of the serial port before reading it.

You get the exception because your reading thread (the delegate) attempts to use a closed serial port.

Moreover, make use of the Dispose() method before closing the serial port. In general, if an object inherits IDisposable it is a good idea to dispose it when you no longer need it, especially if the object uses unmanaged resources like the serial port. Not disposing unmanaged resources will **lead to memory leaks** even in C# (the garbage collector doesn't collect unmanaged resources!)